# Getting current windows username in pyQGis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I need to obtain the current windows user in a python script inside QGIS.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: What have you tried?  What did google tell you?  Have you tried `os.getlogin()` or `os.getenv('username')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import getpass

getpass.getuser()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
import os

os.getenv('USERNAME')
```

Comment: `getuser` will call this under the hood